# UITextfield becomeFirstResponder after UICollectionView reloadData()

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield

In my UICollectionView I'm using first cell as a search bar so I fetch data and then refresh the view by calling `reloadData()` every time a user types some letter.

My problem is that after reloading the data I'm not able to make the UITextField to `becomeFirstResponder()`.

In table view I am able to place a cell with the search field into separate section, so I only have to reload another section to refresh the conent.

But how can I make it work in `UICollectionView`?

Example of my code inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
if indexPath.row == 0 && self.showSearch {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("searchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if self.searchField == nil {
        if let searchField = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UITextField {
            self.searchField = searchField
            self.searchField!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyCollectionViewController.searchFieldChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
        }
    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you resolve that? I meet same problem and don't know what to do (

Comment: @iamthevoid try to place it in a separate section

Answer (score 0):

Reload all cells except the cell with search field, this should work.